# Flutter cannot build application for iOS simulator

Tags: flutter

If I build for Android or web, it works fine.
But on iOS, it fails as below.

----------------------
flutter -v doctor
----------------------

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on macOS 12.0.1 21A559 darwin-x64, locale ko-KR)
• Flutter version 2.8.1 at /Users/hyoungtae/work_flutter/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 77d935af4d (4주 전), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
• Engine revision 890a5fca2e
• Dart version 2.15.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
• Android SDK at /Users/hyoungtae/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.2
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

---

### error log

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
"flutter run" took 25,444ms.

```
       #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
       #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:674:9)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1140:27)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
       <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: there are a lot of packages in your project. which package do you want to run

Comment: At times flutter does this problem. It does not run on emulator. But, when you try to run on actual phone, it will work perfectly.

Comment: Can it be simply a timeout? 25s is quite a lot of time, I can understand that the IDE would think that something has failed and give a generic error.

Comment: Share the rest of the errors please. Full log

Comment: please show full log, and plz give a minimal reproducible sample

Comment: yes, we need full log to determine whats the problems

Answer (score 0):

Just try to switch channel to master and rerun. I believe it may be a flutter bug but this simple change fixed it for me. In my case even a new app via flutter create would not execute on iOS and would throw many such errors - now  it runs on iPhone 13 perfectly.